# pytorch Dropout: "channel will be zeroed out independently"

Tags: pytorch, dropout

In the pytorch [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Dropout.html) it states: *During training, randomly zeroes some of the elements of the input tensor with probability p using samples from a Bernoulli distribution. Each channel will be zeroed out independently on every forward call.*

What does it mean by "zero out independently on every forward call"? below is the pseudocode of my implementation, are they equivalent to pytorch version?

```
import numpy as np
p = 0.3
inpt = np.random.randn((2, 3, 3))  # input tensor

# forward, when training is true
mask = np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=inpt.shape, p=[p, 1 - p])
output = inpt * mask / (1 - p)  # output tensor
return output

# forward, when training is false
return inpt # does nothing

# backward propagation
inpt.grad += incoming_gradient * mask # apply the same mask on incoming gradient
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to apply the mask on the gradient, activations are already masked, i.e. the gradient won't flow past the neurons that were masked in the forward pass. See [*source*](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/99711133403eff8474af0e710a45d367f4fb5e66/torch/nn/functional.py#L1200).